# Android, RSA8, and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/x509/X500Name

Tags: android, eclipse, rational-rsa

I am experiencing the following runtime failure when trying to develop Android applications in IBM RSA 8.0.2.

```
NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/x509/X500Name
```

This occurs when I run my Android app.

I believe this NCDF error is due to RSA8 using the IBM jre and not the Sun version.

However when I specify the Sun jre location in the `eclipse.ini` file (using the `-vm` option) RSA does not start.

When I do not specify any jre in the `eclipse.ini` file RSA fails to start.

When i leave the IBM jre location in the jre, RSA starts fine, however i am unable to force RSA to use the Sun jdk as a runtime environment using the windows preferences options

Does anyone have any other ideas/knowledge of how to...

1. Use RSA8 to develop Android applications?
2. specify a jre in the `eclipse.ini` file other than the IBM-supplied one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem with android development and `IBM RSA V8.0.2`

I managed to start `RSA` with the sun supplied jdk as follows:-

> Edit the `eclipse.ini` file so that the only entry was the `-vm <jdk location>/javaw.exe`

I was able to launch the android **hello world example OK**

Hope this helps anyone else attempting to use a non "pure" `eclipse IDE` such as `RSA`

Comment: Yes this does help me! Thank-you! I wonder, though. I have the absolute path to the JDK location specified, I wonder how I can specify something more relative...

Comment: sure: D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/bin/javaw.exe

'eclipse' is an install of rational ream concert under:

D:\Program Files\IBM\TeamConcert

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and resolved it by changing the JRE location in the Preferences (Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs).  I pointed it to Sun Java6 JDK (not sure if it makes a difference for jre). Then restart the workbench.  Restarting seems to be the key.

Answer (score 0):

My ini file looked like this:

[image]

I changed it to this:

[image]

Now it works